# Retrieve value of an attribute of an xml

Tags: c#, xml

How can I get value of the attribute "CONTRACT_TYPE" in the below XML. The xml is passed as a string argument to my program. I have tried multiple ways but could not achieve it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <FX_CORPORATE>
      <TRADE>
        <REFERENCE_NUMBER>1188586</REFERENCE_NUMBER>
        <TRANSACTION_DATE>20160902</TRANSACTION_DATE>
        <CONTRACT_TYPE>FX-SPOT</CONTRACT_TYPE>
        <COUNTERPARTY>SRI IMEL</COUNTERPARTY>
        <CROSS>NO</CROSS>
        <VIA_CURRENCY>USD</VIA_CURRENCY>
        <TRADER>EMXMONAB</TRADER>
        <POSITION_CURRENCY>AUD</POSITION_CURRENCY>
        <VALUE_DATE>20160906</VALUE_DATE>
        <BUY>
          <CURRENCY>AUD</CURRENCY>
          <AMOUNT>35000</AMOUNT>
        </BUY>
        <SELL>
          <CURRENCY>USD</CURRENCY>
          <AMOUNT>26400.5</AMOUNT>
        </SELL>
        <QUOTE>
          <RATE>0.7543</RATE>
        </QUOTE>
        <BUY_CURRENCY_RATES>
          <SPOT_RATE>0.7546</SPOT_RATE>
        </BUY_CURRENCY_RATES>
        <SELL_CURRENCY_RATES>
          <SPOT_RATE>0.7546</SPOT_RATE>
        </SELL_CURRENCY_RATES>
      </TRADE>
    </FX_CORPORATE>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: CONTRACT_TYPE is a node/element not an attribute.

Comment: `I have tried multiple ways using LINQ to xml but could not achieve it.` => awesome, so it won't be any trouble then for you to post a couple of those attempts along with where you got stuck and we (community) can point you in the right direction.

Comment: var at =  XElement.Parse("XML").Attribute("<CONTRACT_TYPE>");
            if (at != null) 
            Console.Write(at.Value);
            Console.ReadKey();

Answer (score 1):

```
_doc = new XmlDocument();
_doc.Load("//link to xml file");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("FX_CORPORATE/TRADE/CONTRACT_TYPE");
        string value = node.InnerText;
```

this should work

Comment: The xml is passed as a string argument to my program. will it work?

Comment: @VijaySwaroop You should tell this at first. Update your question. Add your code and explain this kind of spesifications.

Comment: It should work I've tried it just 2 seconds ago

Comment: I get a null value for node using the above code.

Comment: My first answer had a spelling mistake I've updated it. but make make shure that                                                                          FX_CORPORATE                                                                                                                     TRADE                                                                                           CONTRACT_TYPE                                                                                                     are written exactly as the nodes in your xml document. this is the path to you xml node.

Comment: Its working with the latest change. thank you all for very quick response.